How to create a timeline branching graphics as shown in "Loki" one of the MCU TV programmes
How to create a timeline image as shared below


What have you tried so far?

I'm cursed with the idea only. I could not find a way to do it. Whether to use a mathematical equation (it'll be a much complicated equation, I guess) or to use pure graphics elements to do it, I'm confused.

Well, you have to start somewhere. At least prepare the data structure with data, look into TimelinePlot, also Hierarchical Drawing of Directed Graphs might be useful ...
